# ADXL345 accelerometer: strange values

Tags: stm32, calibration

I have an [ADXL345](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl345.pdf) digital accelerometer by Analog Devices, and I am using it with an STM32F103. The problem I have been dealing with for a long time is that it gives strange values. In addition, I tried to calibrate it with the help of the sensor's registers and set the offset.

I don't know the reason, but I think that it was not possible because the error was too high.

Because normally, for example, I have the value of 7 g in the Z axis, and if I want to convert it into appropriate bits and put it in an 8-bit register, it is not possible, because 8-bit registers can reduce the maximum offset of 15.6*255, i.e. 3978 mg, about 4 g and still 3 g offset remaining.

So I decided to do this in the software and with the mcu itself. In this way, I will take the average values of the first 10 samples and subtract from this error every time the new data is added.

But still the repeated values are not acceptable and reasonable!

```
#include "main.h"
//some includes 

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
uint8_t data_rec[6];

uint8_t  regreader;

float xg, yg, zg;

unsigned char  regval;

uint16_t xacc,yacc,zacc;

uint16_t offset_x,offset_y,offset_z;

int main(void)
{               

    //read functin 
    void registerRead(uint8_t Reg, uint8_t *Value, uint16_t ByteSize)
    {
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, 0x53<<1, Reg, 1, Value, ByteSize, 100);
    }

    //write function 
    void adxl_write(uint8_t reg,uint8_t data){
        uint8_t  temp[2];
        temp[0]=reg;
        temp[1]=data;
        HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0x53<<1, (uint8_t*)temp, 2, 100);
        HAL_Delay(100);
    }
 
    // check for  true conecction 
    registerRead(0x00,&regval,1);
    sprintf(str,"devidis %d\n",regval);
    puts_str(str);

            ///adxl initialize
    adxl_write(POWER_CTL,0x00);
    adxl_write(POWER_CTL,0x39);             //link ->on &autosleep->on    readig rate for activ detection in sleep mode 4Hz  
    adxl_write(BW_RATE,BWRATE_100);         //normal mode & Rate=100
    adxl_write(DATA_FORMAT,0X0F);           //INTERUPT ACTIBE HIGH   FULL RESOLOUTOILN,MSBF,+-16G
    

//calibration 
    for (i=0;i<100;i++){
      registerRead(0x32,data_rec,6);
      xacc = ((data_rec[1]<<8)|data_rec[0]);
      yacc = ((data_rec[3]<<8)|data_rec[2]);
      zacc = ((data_rec[5]<<8)|data_rec[4]);
      HAL_Delay(10); 
      
       //CONVERT each LSB to  G  Value 
      xg+=( xacc * 0.0039 );
      yg+=( yacc * 0.0039 );
      zg+=( zacc * 0.0039 );
       
    }
     
    xg = xg/100;
    yg = yg/100;
    zg = zg/100;
 
    while (1)
    {    
                ///data reading 
        registerRead(0x32,data_rec,6);
        xacc = ((data_rec[1]<<8)|data_rec[0]);
        yacc = ((data_rec[3]<<8)|data_rec[2]);
        zacc = ((data_rec[5]<<8)|data_rec[4]);

       // calibration
        xg=( xacc * 0.0039 ) - xg ; 
        yg=( yacc * 0.0039 ) - yg ;
        zg=( zacc * 0.0039 ) - zg ;
.
.
.
```

And this is the results. As you can see we have high raw data in the Z axis.

[image: and this is Results as you can see we have high raw data in z axis]

Now my question is, is this amount of offset normal? Because this value cannot be included even in the sensor. And even though we set the offset software and we have jumps in some cases, is this method correct? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Justify bit set D2 in the DATA_FORMAT register. This way, data is left-aligned. With 13-bit resolution, data is just multiplied by 8. Look at your values - all are multiles of 8. Remove Justify bit, or divide values by 8.

13-bit signed resulution gives range of -4095..+4095. LSB = 4mg. 4095*4mg = 16380mg - full range.

Comment: THANKS RIGHT AT THE POINT

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration data can be positive and negative. I don't see your code handling negative values, only unsigned values. A small negative value would be a large positive value. I'd guess the Z value would be negative due to gravity.

Comment: If you mean the data type, I changed the types used to store the data to int 16, but the conditions are the same